# Building Scoped NPM Packages Excludes Scope Prefix For Peer Dependency Imports

Tags: angular, npm, build, angular-library

I create a scope using `npm init --scope=@my-org` as depicted [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-and-publishing-an-org-scoped-package) and follow the subsequent commands. My library makes use of two peer dependencies (which are built and installed). After the library is built successfully using the `ng build` command, the package.json is updated accordingly.

I then publish my package to our Azure Artifacts repo successfully. I then navigate to a project that will use the library and then install it with `npm install @my-org/library`.

Serving the consuming project yields two errors stating that the `mylibrary.service.d.ts` file in `node_modules/@my-org/mylibrary/lib` cannot find the two dependencies. When taking a look at the file, the imports are missing the `@my-org scope` prefix. This error counts for the my-lib.js files located in the respective output directories like fesm2015 and fesm5 too.

Does anyone know how to fix this so I don't need to manually add the scope prefix in after the build and import?

- npm: 6.9.0
- CLI: 8.1.1
- Angular: 8.1.1